# jQuery AutoComplete combobox issue on IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, autocomplete, combobox, internet-explorer-7

I want to use jQuery AutoComplete on a web page.  The page is embedded inside an IE Control in an application.  The problem is that in IE7 and 8, the control does not render properly, as seen in the pic below.

[image]

The top part of the pic is how [jQuery's example page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) loads in Firefox (it looks similar in Chrome and IE9) and the bottom part shows how it renders in IE7/8.  I've circled the issue in red - the dropdown arrow does not align correctly with the rest of the control.

If I'm not mistaken Windows Web Browser control is stuck in IE7 rendering mode, unless you [modify certain registry settings](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) which is not feasible for us.  I've confirmed that the issue persists on my machine if I view the AutoComplete Combobox in via a WebBrowser Control even though I've got IE9 installed.

Is there any easy way to fix the alignment via javascript/css?  The closest I've gotten to a fix is adjusting height using css, but I still can't get the top of the element to align correctly.

Alternatively, does anyone have a solution for a free autocomplete combobox with jsQuery's that doesn't require theming and/or renders properly in IE7/8?

Another minor issue with on IE7/8 is that the tooltips don't appear in the correct positions, but this not not a big problem as tooltips will be removed for this application.

I've loaded up the source code from the jQuery demo into jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTShr/66/

This is the code that creates the arrow button:

```
    $("<a>")
            .attr("tabIndex", -1)
            .attr("title", "Show All Items")
            .tooltip()
            .appendTo(this.wrapper)
            .button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        })
            .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
            .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
            .mousedown(function () {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        })
            .click(function () {
            input.focus();
            // Close if already visible
            if (wasOpen) {
                return;
            }
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
```